# How should I impute NA with mean of that column, not just replacing the na value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset looks like this:

```
TYPE    YEAR  NUMBERS
A       2020     60
A       2019     NA
A       2018     88
A       2017     NA
A       2016     90
```

I want to impute the missing value with the mean of the value in column 'numbers'

I have search for a lot of tutorial, but they just directly replace the missing value with the mean which is not what i want. I try using mice and hmics, but they come out errors. So, if there is any better way to do this?Thanks!

Comment: What is your target output? I am confused with what you mean with "impute with the mean" but not replacing the value with the mean?

Comment: I also don't understand what do you want. Try explaning it again please :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd have done this :

```
df <- read.table(text = 'TYPE    YEAR  NUMBERS
A       2020     60
A       2019     NA
A       2018     88
A       2017     NA
A       2016     90', header=T)
a=  mean(na.omit(df$NUMBERS))
df[is.na(df$NUMBERS),"NUMBERS"]=a
df
```

Output:

```
  TYPE YEAR  NUMBERS
1    A 2020 60.00000
2    A 2019 79.33333
3    A 2018 88.00000
4    A 2017 79.33333
5    A 2016 90.00000
```

Is it what you wanted?

Comment: You can also shorten this to one line: `df$NUMBERS[is.na(df$NUMBERS)] <- mean(df$NUMBERS, na.rm=TRUE)`. I like the approach to read in the table, I always type in each column seperately when no code is given. Your approach is way smarter (I will try to remember this) :D

Comment: Yes, it works this way as well :) but due to painful memories of changing an object  by using the same object as input, I always do this "security" step and create an intermediate thing, even tho it's useless 99.99% of the time :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring from the presence of the `TYPE` column that you should be imputing based on the group's mean, not the population's mean.

Modified data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(TYPE = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), YEAR = c(2020L, 2019L, 2018L, 2017L, 2016L, 2020L, 2019L, 2018L, 2017L, 2016L), NUMBERS = c(60L, NA, 88L, NA, 90L, 160L, NA, 188L, NA, 190L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

### base R

```r
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$TYPE,
                  function(z) { z$NUMBERS[is.na(z$NUMBERS)] <- mean(z$NUMBERS, na.rm = TRUE); z}))
#      TYPE YEAR   NUMBERS
# A.1     A 2020  60.00000
# A.2     A 2019  79.33333
# A.3     A 2018  88.00000
# A.4     A 2017  79.33333
# A.5     A 2016  90.00000
# B.6     B 2020 160.00000
# B.7     B 2019 179.33333
# B.8     B 2018 188.00000
# B.9     B 2017 179.33333
# B.10    B 2016 190.00000
```

or

```r
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$TYPE,
                  function(z) transform(z, NUMBERS = ifelse(is.na(NUMBERS), mean(NUMBERS, na.rm = TRUE), NUMBERS))))
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(TYPE) %>%
  mutate(NUMBERS = if_else(is.na(NUMBERS), mean(NUMBERS, na.rm = TRUE), as.numeric(NUMBERS))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#    TYPE   YEAR NUMBERS
#    <chr> <int>   <dbl>
#  1 A      2020    60  
#  2 A      2019    79.3
#  3 A      2018    88  
#  4 A      2017    79.3
#  5 A      2016    90  
#  6 B      2020   160  
#  7 B      2019   179. 
#  8 B      2018   188  
#  9 B      2017   179. 
# 10 B      2016   190
```